# Bootstrap 4 - Card columns behaviour

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Is there any way to change Bootstrap 4 card-columns default top-to-bottom behaviour to left-to-right?

Right now I'm displaying news in it for a school project, and it's kind of senseless to see 1 hour old and 3 months old news next to each other.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Do you have a Screen shot?

Comment: Try specifying a permanent width, its should be as much big that it can hold content from top to bottom and use float :right ;...if things dosnt work try using important in your CSS...

Comment: @JaysonJohn: I'm on mobile right now, but here is the same: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/#card-columns

Comment: without any code of yours to show your issue, ... see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask it might help you to clarify your question ;)

Comment: I don't think it needs any clarification. Bootstrap 4 card-columns class orders the cards from top to bottom, then left to right as the official description says. I'm asking if its possible to order from left to right, then top to bottom. The code is exactly same as the Bootstrap documentation example.

Comment: Quoted from the link I provided: Card columns -
Cards can be organized into Masonry-like columns with just CSS by wrapping them in .card-columns. Cards are built with CSS column properties instead of flexbox for easier alignment. Cards are ordered from top to bottom and left to right.

Answer (score 0):

TRY Example

HTML

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mt-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="http://success-at-work.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/free-stock-photos.gif">
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <h5 class="text-bold">Tawshif Ahsan Khan</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mt-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="http://success-at-work.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/free-stock-photos.gif">
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Tawshif Ahsan Khan</h4>
                        <div class="meta">
                            <a href="#">Friends</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-text">
                            Tawshif is a web designer living in Bangladesh.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <span class="float-right">Joined in 2013</span>
                        <span><i class=""></i>75 Friends</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mt-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="http://success-at-work.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/free-stock-photos.gif">
                    <p class="card-block">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam velit quisquam veniam excepturi temporibus inventore corporis dicta sit culpa veritatis placeat earum, dolorum asperiores, delectus dolore voluptatibus, at magnam nobis!
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mt-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="http://success-at-work.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/free-stock-photos.gif">
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <figure class="profile">
                            <img src="http://success-at-work.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/free-stock-photos.gif" class="profile-avatar" alt="">
                        </figure>
                        <h4 class="card-title mt-3">Tawshif Ahsan Khan</h4>
                        <div class="meta">
                            <a>Friends</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-text">
                            Tawshif is a web designer living in Bangladesh.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <small>Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
                        <button class="btn btn-secondary float-right btn-sm">show</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mb-5">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mt-4">
                <div class="card card-inverse card-primary ">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="http://success-at-work.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/free-stock-photos.gif">
                    <blockquote class="card-blockquote p-3">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat.</p>
                        <footer>
                            <small>
                          Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
                        </small>
                        </footer>
                    </blockquote>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mt-4">
                <div class="card card-inverse card-info">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="http://success-at-work.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/free-stock-photos.gif">
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <figure class="profile">
                            <img src="http://success-at-work.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/free-stock-photos.gif" class="profile-avatar" alt="">
                        </figure>
                        <h4 class="card-title mt-3">Tawshif Ahsan Khan</h4>
                        <div class="meta card-text">
                            <a>Friends</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-text">
                            Tawshif is a web designer living in Bangladesh.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <small>Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
                        <button class="btn btn-info float-right btn-sm">Follow</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mt-4">
                <div class="card card-inverse card-info">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="http://success-at-work.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/free-stock-photos.gif">
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <figure class="profile profile-inline">
                            <img src="http://success-at-work.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/free-stock-photos.gif" class="profile-avatar" alt="">
                        </figure>
                        <h4 class="card-title">Tawshif Ahsan Khan</h4>
                        <div class="card-text">
                            Tawshif is a web designer living in Bangladesh.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <small>Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
                        <button class="btn btn-info float-right btn-sm">Follow</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mt-4">
                <div class="card card-inverse card-info">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="http://success-at-work.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/free-stock-photos.gif">
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <figure class="profile profile-inline">
                            <img src="http://success-at-work.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/free-stock-photos.gif" class="profile-avatar" alt="">
                        </figure>
                        <h4 class="card-title">Tawshif Ahsan Khan</h4>
                        <div class="card-text">
                            Tawshif is a web designer living in Bangladesh.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Follow</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html {
    font-family: Lato, 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}

h5 {
    font-size: 1.28571429em;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1.2857em;
    margin: 0;
}

.card {
    font-size: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: .28571429rem;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 #d4d4d5, 0 0 0 1px #d4d4d5;
}

.card-block {
    font-size: 1em;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em;
    border: none;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, .1);
    box-shadow: none;
}

.card-img-top {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.card-title {
    font-size: 1.28571429em;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1.2857em;
}

.card-text {
    clear: both;
    margin-top: .5em;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .68);
}

.card-footer {
    font-size: 1em;
    position: static;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: .75em 1em;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .05) !important;
    background: #fff;
}

.card-inverse .btn {
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}

.profile {
    position: absolute;
    top: -12px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.profile-avatar {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.profile-inline {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

.profile-inline ~ .card-title {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 4px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.text-bold {
    font-weight: 700;
}

.meta {
    font-size: 1em;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}

.meta a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}

.meta a:hover {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .87);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but how is this utilizing the card-columns class?

Comment: You mean you want a full width sliding card column?